# button function change to onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I want one function to write in on-load page load. This function only works after 10 seconds of pages loaded. Is that possible?

When we click on the button I want to only show the popup. I want to change that in on-load after some times.

This code will not work. I need some plugins and javascript that is not uploaded. Please help me change the function in onload

```js
$(function() {
  $("#timeout-example").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.timeoutDialog({
      timeout: 1,
      countdown: 60,
      logout_redirect_url: 'https://google.com',
      restart_on_yes: false
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<a href="#" id="timeout-example"> CLICK HERE TO VIEW POPUP </a>
```

Comment: your question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
var timeLeft = 10;
var showTimerDiv = document.getElementById('showTimer');
var timerId = setInterval(countdown, 1000);

function countdown() {
    if (timeLeft == -1) {
        clearTimeout(timerId);
        doSomething();
    } else {
        showTimerDiv.innerHTML = timeLeft + ' seconds remaining';
        timeLeft--;
    }
}

function doSomething() {
    alert("Hi");
}
```

Online output: [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/eaa67twz/)